# How to communicate between Rhapsody models in different processes/systems?

Tags: c++, sockets, uml, model-driven-development, rhapsody

We are using IBM (formerly Telelogic) Rhapsody for a new project to do model driven development of a complex device. The device consists of several subsystems that are connected by various network interfaces. We'd like to model the entire system in Rhapsody and then generate code separately for the various subsystems.

The problem is this: Rhapsody can model and generate code for a single process. We like to model subsystems using separate processes at first and then generate code for the subsystems directly.

What alternatives are available for inter -process and -system communication that we can slide into the Rhapsody model with as little pain as possible?

We are generating C++ and would like to use sockets for inter-system communication, Rhapsody currently communicates between objects and threads in the same process using message queues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own version of the Rhapsody MessageQueue class and rebuild the oxf library using your code instead of the default code.

Comment: Actually, that's the approach I'm taking. Thanks for the answer.